# iOS MediaPlayer Remote control events not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'am trying to add remote control events to a music player app, but can't get it working.

Some facts:

- I'm using `[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];`
- I added **Audio**, **AirPlay** and **Picture** in Picture background modes;
- The example is playing audio;
- It does not receive remote notifications from the lock screen and control center;

I've made an example project which can be downloaded here:
[example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6hz93c3gkfgra2a/MPTest.zip?dl=0)
The main source:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaPickerController.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaQuery.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMusicPlayerController *MusicPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMediaItemCollection *MusicPlayerSongs;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _MusicPlayerSongs = [MPMediaItemCollection alloc];
    _MusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [_MusicPlayer setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
    [_MusicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
    [_MusicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSMutableArray *selectedTracks = [NSMutableArray new];

    //Find all tracks that contains an 'a'
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *songPredicate =
    [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"a"
                                     forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle
                                  comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];

    MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [mediaQuery addFilterPredicate:songPredicate];
    [selectedTracks addObjectsFromArray:[mediaQuery items]];

    NSLog(@"Number of tracks containing an 'a': %lu",(unsigned long)selectedTracks.count);

    self.MusicPlayerSongs = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc]initWithItems:selectedTracks];

    [self.MusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:self.MusicPlayerSongs];
    [self.MusicPlayer play];
    [self.MusicPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];

    [self basicSetup];
    [self updateNowPlayingCenter];
}

- (void)basicSetup {

    //Listen to remote control events
    [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand.enabled = NO;
    [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand.enabled = NO;
    [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand.enabled = YES;
    [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].pauseCommand.enabled = YES;
    [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].togglePlayPauseCommand.enabled = YES;
    [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].nextTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remoteNext)];
    [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].previousTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remotePrevious)];
    [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remotePlay)];
    [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remotePlay)];
    [[MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter].togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(remoteTogglePlayState)];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}

-(void)remotePlay{
    NSLog(@"remotePlay");
    [self.MusicPlayer play];
}

-(void)remoteNext{
    NSLog(@"remoteNext");
    [self.MusicPlayer skipToNextItem];
    [self updateNowPlayingCenter];
}

-(void)remotePrevious{
    NSLog(@"remotePrevious");
    [self.MusicPlayer skipToPreviousItem];
    [self updateNowPlayingCenter];
}

-(void)remotePause{
    NSLog(@"remotePause");
    [self.MusicPlayer pause];
}

-(void)remoteTogglePlayState{
    NSLog(@"remoteTogglePlayState");
    if([self.MusicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying){
        [self.MusicPlayer pause];
    }else{
        [self.MusicPlayer play];
    }
}

-(void)updateNowPlayingCenter{

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                                                                                    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: [self.MusicPlayer nowPlayingItem].artist,
                                                                                    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: [self.MusicPlayer nowPlayingItem].title,
                                                                                    MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: [self.MusicPlayer nowPlayingItem].albumTitle,
                                                                                    }];
    center.nowPlayingInfo = songInfo;
}
```

I just can't figure out why it is not working :(

**PROGRESS UPDATE'S**
What I found out so far, if I reboot my iPhone, it works. But every time after that it won't.

The lock screen and control center both show the right track, but still can't control the app.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I gave up for the last year or so. I'm hoping that someone has figured it out. If you have not figured it out, I'd like to know that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps you at all, but here is how I received any changes (in Swift).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.getNowPlayingItem), name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    player.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
}

deinit {
    player.endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

It is necessary to (addObserver and beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications), but also to (removeObserver and endGeneratingPlaybackNotification). I am not yet familiar with remote control events, but you may want to try ending those notifications as well. Hope this helps!